# How to track down calls that are blocking the main (UI) thead?

Tags: ios, performance, profiling

I have an iOS app with some performance issues. In particular, when the user selects an item in a particular Core Data-backed UITableView there's a delay before the UI updates. Since there's very little multithreading in the app at the moment, I'm guessing I'm making a method call somewhere that's taking too long and blocking the UI thread.

Stepping through the code isn't revealing anything to me. (Perhaps because the problem is on another trip through the run loop? Not sure...I'm a solid iOS developer but a novice when it comes to the debugging and profiling tools.)

What's the best way to tackle a problem like this? Some way to step through or trace what the thread is doing in order and how long each call is taking, or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Time Profiler in Instruments. See [WWDC 2012 - Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211) for a practical demonstration of how you can use profiler to identify candidate methods that you might want to put in a background queue to avoid blocking the main queue.

See the [Instruments User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for a basic description of the Instruments tool, but I think that WWDC video is a more effective way to gain familiarity with this particular instrument, the Time Profiler. Also, if you've never done concurrent Core Data, you might also want to see the [Concurrency with Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) section of the *Core Data Programming Guide.*

Answer (score 0):

I will second what's `Rob` said: you will find more easily what's the bottleneck of your app using **`Time Profiler`** in **`Instruments`**. All references from Rob are good specially the one from WWDC. I also run into this [tut](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-time-profiling-with-instruments/?search_index=1) in `mobile tuts` which covers the basics.